# Capturar o som de um microfone no Windows via C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows, áudio

Como eu faço para capturar o áudio que o microfone recebe no Windows com o C#? Quero desenvolver um software que receba o som exterior e baseado nisso ele altere o volume de meu computador.

Comment: Acho que esta [biblioteca](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) pode ajudar você.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai precisar de uma biblioteca para fazer isso sem ter que recorrer diretamente à API do Windows. A mais conhecida é a [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

Se estiver usando XNA (obsoleto), tem [classe pronta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104(v=xnagamestudio.41)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).